# Wired internet isn't working

Tags: networking, atheros, lan

I would really appreciate help on this.

Alright, so after searching for while on why Ubuntu wasn't connecting to the internet, someone told me that it may be the chip I had. The only information I could find out about that was that I have a Atheros GbE LAN chip. After searching this, I couldn't find anything that worked.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

I am fairly new to linux, so it's quite possible a lot of the solutions don't work due to that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off I can tell you that the chip will work on Ubuntu. what you will first need todo is to download the driver and put it on the computer then fallow http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12206393 to install the driver and that should work.

Comment: I looked at that before you posted this answer, and it didn't work for me. I looked deeper into it, and tried it yet again, but I am still unable to connect to the internet.

Comment: Try it with ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 is Real new and not all the drivers work with 12.10 just yet. for exsample Nvidia Still dosn't work correctly